# how can i remove an h2 tag from inside of a div that has a class if the h2 tag does not have a class or id using php or something else?

Tags: html

is it possible to remove an h2 tag from within a div tag if the h2 tag does not have an id or class? Id like to remove the h2 tag below including all of the text inside of it without removing any  other h2 tags from the  web page is this possible?

```
<div class="container">
    <h2> text... </h2>


 </div>
```

Comment: its a possible string replace trick. Just extract string between <h2> and </h2> and then, check for id/class within this tag, if its not there, replace <h2> and </h2> with empty strings.

Comment: it's better just not to put it there in the first place

Comment: Use the jquery that will do easily.

Comment: lol i like your answer orangepill but im  stuck because its being generated in a wordpress php powered amazon discount finder and i have no idea where to find the basic code structure of the discount finder in the themes files and  its being called using more code   that doesnt include the h2 tag  as far as i can tell

Comment: is it possible for you to provide some code examples tuxnami im pretty new to php =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to have a reference to the div to begin with, or be willing to remove *any* h2 tag that is inside any other div on the page or scope you're dealing with.

You could remove all h2 tags from within a div that has a class called "container" with jQuery like so:

```
$('div.container').children('h2').remove();
```

This would only remove direct children of that div.

If you don't have any rules for identifying which h2s to remove, it'd be like doing it by hand when somebody tells you "hey buddy, remove some specific h2s but not others.. and hey, I won't tell you which ones to remove"

Perhaps if you add more context to your question we can help out more.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to thatjuan's answer, if the `<h2>` you want to remove is the first in the first `<h2>` in the `<div>` then you can use the `:first-child` selector to remove just that one. [Here is a Demo using jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/F6SXc/). You could, if it was not the first child, use `:nth-child` to do it as well.